# Formatting display of numbers in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wondering how to truncate numbers in Python 3? For example, `87.28197` to `87.281`
The standard in Python 2 was using `%` but this is no longer used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `%` string formatter still is available in Python 3. It is preferred you use the `''.format()` [string formatting syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), which also supports specifying float precisions.

Both of these work:

```
>>> yournumber = 87.28197
>>> "{0:.3f}".format(yournumber)
'87.282'
>>> "%.3f" % yournumber
'87.282'
```

If it is *just* the one float you are converting to a string, then the [`format()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) is probably more convenient as you do not need to use a `{0:..}` placeholder:

```
>>> format(yournumber, '.3f')
'87.282'
```

Comment: I think this is what the OP's after, but they did state `For example, 87.28197 to 87.281` - which of course this doesn't do :)

Comment: @JonClements: Yeah, I was studiously ignoring that little detail. :-P

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
print("{0:.2f}".format(87.23197))
```

see also the method [format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) for Detail.